# Very Naive Questions about training group selection in Random Forest or Tree Based Method

Tags: classification, random-forest

I am just beginning to discover the possibilities of machine learning and I have a naive question: 
First, does Recursive classification tree method (as shown in party package in R, the ctree function) need a training group and then a test group ?
Second, I have few X parameters (6), 246 observations and an binary Y (inferior or superior). According cforest function in party package, 4 parameters seemed to be important.
Then I put these 4 parameters in the ctree function, Is it correct?